# C# : problem to arrange my layout dynamically

Tags: c#, datagridview, flowlayoutpanel

I'm trying to develop a tablature editor with a specific look, and I'm struggling to display my controls as I want. I think I'm doing it the wrong way so I need your help! I'm working on Visual Sutdio with C# / Winforms.

Ideally, this should look like this :   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3q5r.png

Basically, this is an A4 sheet on which I display a datagridview with custom borders. As I progressively fill the datagridview, this one should expand: I do that by adding columns dynamically.

The problem is when I reach the right border of the sheet, it should expand on a new line (like a flow layout panel: when there's no more space the control is added on a new line).

I don't manage to do that. If I add more columns to my datagridview, a horizontal scrollbar appears instead of going on a new line. I tried to mix my datagridview with a flowlayoutpanel but I can't make it work.

Have you got any idea on how to do that? Any help would be highly appreciated.

EDIT :
So in my picture, the grid represents the subdivision of the beat (musically speaking). Each beat is divided in 4 subdivisions (=4 columns).

The numbers represent the notes on the instrument, and several notes can be played at the same time (that's why there are sometimes 2 or more notes in the same column). On the contrary, we can also play 0 notes at a given time, that is why some columns are empy. The user write these notes

Consequently, 1 beat = 1 grid of 4 columns * 4 rows (4 notes maximum can be played at the same time).

The horizontal line is just an indication wether the note should be played with the right hand (above the line) or the left hand (below the line). When the user writes the notes, he decides where to write them.

Each time I add a beat, I add 4 columns. So my whole tablature is a grid of 4 rows * X columns (X being a multiple of 4), in which the user writes the notes he wants. My problem is that I would like to "cut" my grid and display it on several lines so that it fits an A4 sheet.

Comment: Add your code and ask a more specific question where exactly is the problem

Comment: I edited my post to add a description of the picture.
JohnG : I considered using a tablelayoutpanel, but I choose the datagrid for the two following functions :
- it is possible to do a multiselection of the cells in the datagridview
- the datagridview allows to navigate between cells with arrow keys
If it's possible to implement these two functions in a custom TableLayoutPanel, that might be a solution

Comment: Edit the question in a more precise way. Usually, no one is interested to read lengthy texts...